# Guardar imagen con html2canvas de un div desfasado

Tags: javascript, html5, laravel

tengo un problema, quiero guardar una imagen PNG de un diagrama, el problema es que mi div esta desfasado, entonces utilizo OVERFLOW, pero al momento de transformar la imagen, solo me imprime lo que esta a la vista, alguna sugerencia?

```
<body>  
  <div id="Grafica">
    {!! $gantt !!}
  </div>
</body
```

cabe aclarar que estoy usando laravel y por eso mi grafica esta en la variable gantt. el codigo del script que uso me descarga la imagen, me la transforma en png (aunque solo me funciona en  chrome)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function capturar2(){

    html2canvas(
      document.querySelector("#Grafica")).then(canvas => {
          var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream"); 
          console.log(image);
          var a = document.createElement('a');
          a.href = image;
          a.download = 'Diagrama.png';
          a.click();
    });
  }
</script>
```

cualquier ayuda seria bien recibida, ¡gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Con cambiar el selector para seleccionar directamente la imagen debería funcionarte, algo como

```
let img = document.querySelector("#Grafica img");
html2canvas(img).then(...)
```

Aquí tienes [un ejemplo funcionando](https://stackblitz.com/edit/pawer13-html2canvas)

Comment: Me funciono en modo local, pero ahora lo he subido a un servidor y me sale el siguiente error en la consola: html2canvas.min.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of null
    at o (html2canvas.min.js:6)
    at capturar2 (20:149)
    at <anonymous>:1:1